# MVC selectlist does not show the selecteditem in dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have below code in `Repository.cs` to fetch the `Timezones`

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetTimeZoneList()
{
     return TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones().Select(x => new SelectListItem()
     {
         Value = x.Id,
         Text = x.DisplayName
     });
}
```

and my `AddEditEmployeeViewModel.cs` is as below:

```
public class AddEditEmployeeViewModel
{
   public string TimeZoneID { get; set; }
   public SelectList TimeZones { get; set; }
}
```

and on ajax call, am filling the model values as below:

```
public PartialViewResult GetAddEditEmployee(string id)
{
    var model = new AddEditEmployeeViewModel();
    model.TimeZones = new SelectList(Repository.GetTimeZoneList(), "Value", "Text");
    var employee = (from e in context.tbl_users where e.eid == eid select new { e.fnamae, e.lname, e.account_status, e.preferred_timezone }).FirstOrDefault();
    if (employee == null) return PartialView("_AddEditEmployee", model);
    model.TimeZoneID = employee.preferred_timezone;
    //model.TimeZoneID will have values like India Standard Time, UTC etc.,
    //..Other properties
    return PartialView("_AddEditEmp", model);
}
```

Even though `model.TimeZoneID` is having matching value from selectlist fetched, it does not keep the value item as selected. I can see the values fetched from DB present in `SelectList`. Screenshot for reference

[image: SelectList items]

Here is the `view code`

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.TimeZoneID, Model.TimeZones, "Select a Timezone", new { @class = "selectpicker", data_width = "100%", })
```

What's the mistake am committing here. What changes needs to be done so that item is selected from `dropdownlist/selectpicker`?

Comment: Do you have valid value in `model.TimeZoneID` before returning the partial view ?

Comment: Yes, I do, as mentioned in comments with above code.. @Shyju

Comment: Your code looks perfectly fine. Here is a working sample i created from your code https://dotnetfiddle.net/FiIEOf

Comment: Not related, but `GetTimeZoneList()` returns `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` which is what `SelectList` is, so there is no point creating an identical 2nd `SelectList` from the first one. The property can be `public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TimeZones { get; set; }` and then simply `model.TimeZones = Repository.GetTimeZoneList();`. As pointed out by others the code should work fine if the value of `TimeZoneID` matches exactly one of the values in the collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rule, I would replace

```
model.TimeZones = new SelectList(
    Repository.GetTimeZoneList(), 
    "Value", 
    "Text");
```

with

```
model.TimeZones = new SelectList(
    Repository.GetTimeZoneList(), 
    "Value", 
    "Text", 
    model.TimeZoneID);
```

Basically, use the [overload that takes the selected value as a parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist.selectlist.aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.SelectList). You could also simply return your timezone objects, rather than a collection of SelectListItems:

```
public static IEnumerable<TimeZone> GetTimeZoneList()
{
     return TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();
}
```

and

```
model.TimeZones = new SelectList(
    Repository.GetTimeZoneList(), 
    "ID", 
    "DisplayName", 
    model.TimeZoneID);
```

Comment: @GuruprasadRao To eliminate the obvious: did you rebuild?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao There really isn't anything in your question that points to why your value wouldn't be selected. My only other thought is that strings are weird beasts, when it comes to equality comparisons, so perhaps you can try adding an integer field to your model and timezone objects, assign an arbitrary value, and see if that binds correctly. I know the overload I mentioned works, since it's what I normally use.

Comment: Oh.. Alright @Tieson.. May be something within my code would be blocking too for this.. I have to find it out.. Anyways... will take your steps as building blocks and will accept the answer by tomorrow.. Thanks for your time.. :)

Comment: If you're storing timezones in a database table, and don't want to use auto-incrementing IDs, you can always use a GUID (the `uniqueidentifier type in SQL Server) instead. You may also want to apply the Trim() function on your strings, since an extra space will throw off what looks like an equal string comparison.

Comment: No, Timezones aren't stored as in separate table.. :)

Comment: There is no point adding the 4th parameter in the `SelectList` constructor when binding to a property using `DropDownListFor()`. Its ignored, because internally, the method builds a new `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` and sets the `Selected` property based on the value of the property.